# boost::_bi::unwrapper<F>::unwrap cannot be used as a function?

Tags: c++, boost-thread

Was trying to use a thread class I created in Windows, in Linux. Chose Netbeans for it, and in the project settings I've specified `Linker > Additional Library Directories` as `/usr/local/boost_1_53_0`
Under `Libraries`, I specified `boost_thread-mt`
Under `C++ Compiler > Include Directories` I specified `/usr/local/boost_1_53_0`

`thread.h` and `Thread.cpp` are my files. `Thread.hpp` belongs to Boost.

The error shown is at the line where I've included `#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>` and the error is:

```
/usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In member function ‘void  
boost::_bi::list1<A1>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int)
[with F = unsigned int (**)(void*), A = boost::_bi::list0, A1 =  
boost::_bi::value<void*>]’: In file included from  
/usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,  
                 from /usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:29,  
                 from /usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/thread/thread.hpp:22,  
                 from ../../../TSDK-master/src/Core/source/thread.h:72,  
                 from ../../../TSDK-master/src/Core/source/Thread.cpp:95:  
/usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20:59:    
instantiated from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type  
boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() [with R = void, F = unsigned  
int (**)(void*), L = boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<void*> >,  
boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’  
/usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:117:17:    
instantiated from ‘void boost::detail::thread_data<F>::run() [with F =  
boost::_bi::bind_t<void, unsigned int (**)(void*),  
boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<void*> > >]’  
../../../TSDK-master/src/Core/source/Thread.cpp:202:50:   instantiated  
from here /usr/local/boost_1_53_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp:253:9: error:  
‘boost::_bi::unwrapper<F>::unwrap [with F = unsigned int  
(**)(void*)]((* & f), 0l)’ cannot be used as a function
```

Am completely clueless as to what is causing this. Could anyone help?

**EDIT:**
a part of thread.h

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> 
#include <cstdio>

class Thread
{
protected:
    boost::thread*            m_Thread;
    unsigned int id;
private:
    bool                      m_pause;
    boost::mutex              m_pause_mutex;
    boost::condition_variable m_pause_changed;
    bool threadCreated;

public:

    Thread();
    Thread(unsigned int id);
    ~Thread();
    bool Start();
    bool CreateThread(unsigned int Function(void* pParam),void *pParam);
    void Terminate();
    unsigned int myThreadProc(void* param);
    bool IsRunning();
    bool IsStarted();

protected:
    virtual unsigned int ThreadProc() = 0;
};
```

and a part of thread.cpp

```
#include "thread.h"
Thread::Thread() : m_Thread(NULL), m_pause(true), threadCreated(false), id(NULL)
{
}//Thread ctor

Thread::Thread(unsigned int _id) : m_Thread(NULL), id(_id), threadCreated(false), m_pause(true)
{}

Thread::~Thread()
{
    if (NULL != m_Thread) { delete m_Thread; }
}

unsigned int Thread::GetThreadID() { return id; }//GetThreadID

bool Thread::Start()
{
    m_Thread = new boost::thread(&Thread::myThreadProc, this, this);
    threadCreated = true;
    return threadCreated;
}

bool Thread::CreateThread(unsigned int Function(void* pFunctionParam),void *pParam)
{
    //Receives Thread Function,pParam as Arguments and starts Thread.
    m_Thread= new boost::thread(&Function,pParam);
    threadCreated = true;
    return threadCreated;
}

void Thread::Terminate()
{
    if (NULL != m_Thread) {
        m_Thread->join();
        m_Thread=0;
    }
    else {printf("No thread was created\n");}
}

unsigned int Thread::myThreadProc(void* param)
{
    Thread* ourBoostThread = (Thread*) param;
    int ret = ourBoostThread->ThreadProc();
    return ret;
}//_ThreadProc

bool Thread::IsRunning() { return !m_pause; }
bool Thread::IsStarted() { return threadCreated; }
```

Line 202 is `bool Thread::IsStarted() { return threadCreated; }`

Comment: Please post the code that generates this error.

Comment: On line 202 of "Core/source/Thread.cpp", you're trying to call `boost::bind` (or perhaps some thread function which in turn calles that) incorrectly. Could you show us that line, and the declarations of whatever you're trying to bind?

Comment: In fact, now I've reformatted the error message so we can read all of it, it looks very much like you're using a pointer to a function pointer where you should just be using a function pointer. But I can't be entirely sure without seeing your code.

Comment: Updated question with code. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `unsigned int Function(void* pParam)` be `unsigned int (*Function)(void* pParam)`?

Comment: @TomKnapen: Both are equivalent; the parameter type is a function pointer whichever form you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m_Thread= new boost::thread(&Function,pParam);
```

`Function` is actually a pointer to a function, even though it doesn't look like it. If you declare a function parameter of function type, then it is actually a function pointer; much as function parameters declared as arrays are actually pointers.

So `&Function` is a pointer to that function pointer, which can't be called like a function. Change it to just `Function`, which can be.